# Restrict Visual Studio debugger access

Tags: .net, security, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a .Net application where it serves as a host application that loads up user created assemblies and dynamically runs them as plugins.
The host application and plugins run in the same app domain. I would like to offer the authors of these plugins the chance to Attach to Process so they can debug their plugins while the host application is running.

However, I also want to keep certain values of variables in the host application hidden from Visual Studio.

For instance, if I'm storing a secret value in a static variable such as `HostApplication.Passwords.SecretApiPassword`, even though the plugin author would not have this class referenced in their project and if they just happened to know the namespace of this static, all they would have to do is use the Immediate Window to print `HostApplication.Passwords.SecretApiPassword` and Visual Studio would echo the value.

I've tried `DebuggerBrowseable` and marking the variable as internal, but since in debug mode, it seems the debugger has total access of everything.

Are there any design patterns or tricks that can secure certain values from the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: Not found the direct answer for it using the debugger tool, but one idea is that maybe you could think about using encrypted variables, so they don't know what they mean even if they could view the encrypted value during debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One of my concerns is that a plugin author could take these values, some being database connection strings to databases they should not have access to, and attempt to use them. So even if they were encrypted, potentially, they would still be able to use them to gain access.

Comment: I don't understand your concerns here. Anyone could connect to your application with the debugger and read the data, it has nothing to do with plugins..

Comment: @Ching Kuo, Not very sure what your host app is, but if every one could visit your host app namespace or source code, it has nothing to do with debugging tool unless you could control the access account to your app, maybe use certain version control tool, developer code or others. The VS debugger tool doesn't have the feature to achieve your function.